# Did Ryan really never cry?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, wilfred

In the [*Wilfred*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1703925/) episode "Questions" (S02E11), during *Ryan*'s trip within a trip he learns that the cause for his panic attacks isn't little *Joffrey* crying but merely *Kristen* telling him not to cry, which reminds him of her telling the exact same to him when they were kids and had trouble in the family, ultimately realizing that he *"never stopped not crying"*. After waking up from the trips he looks at a picture showing him with *Amanda*, cries, and admits

> I'm sad, Wilfred. I'm really sad.

What I would like to know is, of what scale are the implications of this revelation? **Does this just mean that *Ryan* had suppressed his sadness over breaking up with *Amanda* (in S02E08) or does this really go as far as *Ryan* having suppressed his actual sadness all over his life, or at least since his "*Wilfred*-inducing" suicide attempt?** I see that this question might not have been answered too clearly by the show but I might as well have missed some little aspect (or it was deliberately left ambiguous). I guess part in answering this question might already be achieved by answering the simpler (or even trivial) question of **did Ryan indeed never cry in any episode up until that point?**